# Jasmine Unit test for a directive : Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

Consider there was a class called `exampleClass` which will have a default `constructor()` with `ngInject` decorator and a simple function.

here is the demonstration:

```
export default class exampleClass{
constructor(){
'ngInject';
//some code lines
}

exampleFunction() {
//some code lines
}

exampleClass.selector = 'appExampleClass';
}
```

How can we write a unit test for a directives?

Comment: This doesn't look like AngularJS, are you sure this isn't Angular2+?

Comment: @Protozoid yes, it's 1.6